# Compare the values of a litbox with two columns of a table in c#

Tags: c#, html, listbox

I have a table with several columns. I also have a listbox that is filled in by the user. I want to show a message when the values of listbox belong to a row of the table. What should I do?
I have just started programming and I am very beginner. If anyone can solve this problem, thank you for helping me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and following the advice there, edit your question to include the information which can help us to answer it. What frameworks are you using (e.g. ASP.net MVC or ASP.net MVC core, or web API on the server side with React or Vue or something else on the client side)? Please show us some code you've already tried and tell us how you'd expect it to behave and how its actual behaviour differs from what you're expecting.

Comment: I do not have a code, I just want it to show a message when the values in the listbox belong to a same row in the table in c#.